# Клик на div элемент chrome extention

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Нужно как-то симулировать клик по определенному элементу на сайте https://cs.money/ (в div#inventory_bot). Проблема в том, что при попытке на что-то "кликнуть" в консоле пишет "hidden" и клик не проходит. Пытался сделать так:

`$('#inventory_bot div')[0].click()`

Проблема, вроде, не в JQuery, на чистом JS ничего не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Что-то не заметил на пациенте jQuery.

Фидл - https://jsfiddle.net/wodzmopc/

Ещё момент.
Выбор div. При вашем селекторе выбираются все дети, плюс все вложенные дети.
Чтобы выбрать только первую вложенность нужно `$('#inventory_bot > div')`

Answer (score -1):

jQuery `.click()` это слушатель события а не его вызов. 
Вызов клика делается через `.trigger('click')`, но это сработает только если на объект повешено событие click, например для перехода по html ссылке это не сработает.

Comment: Проблема не в этом, с `.trigger('click')` ничего не меняется

Comment: Согласно документации - [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) без параметров является вызовом события.

Comment: @Deliaz, да, не пришло в голову, и это не отменяет второй части ответа

Comment: Всё он правильно вызывает.